# TSQL Index odd and even sequence steps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a gritty industrial control problem i'm trying to solve with T-SQL.

The goal is to calculate an index position for each of two pallet loading robots, positioned in one of two ranges; 2 to 78 (robot 1) and 4 to 80 (robot 2).

Each robot indexes in steps of 4 so complete coverage of 80 spots on the pallet is achieved. The robots work side by side with a minimum spacing of 2 spots while they move along the pallet.

Two sized boxes can be placed on the pallet, one twice as long as the other. If two small boxes are placed side by side taking up 1 spot each, a single larger box can be placed on top, taking up 2 spots until a maximum height is reached. Thus the spot number for a small box is always odd and for a large box is always even and the robot index number is always even. e.g. (see diagram) from index position 14 spots 13 and 15 are loaded, and from index 20 spots 19 and 21 can be loaded.

[Robot Index Positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WwgM.jpg)

I need a conversion formula that calculates the Index number for a given Spot and Robot.

The calculated Index column should look like the following:

```
Spot Robot Index
1     1     2
2     1     2
3     1     2
-     -     - 
13    1    14
14    1    14
15    1    14
16    2    16
17    2    16
18    1    18
19    2    20
-    -    -
-    -    -
77    1    78
78    1    78
79    2    80
80    2    80
```

One way would be to do an update to the Index column with every possible combination of Spot and Robot using a simple CASE WHEN selection or maybe do lookups on a reference table holding every possible combination. What I would like to explore (if any math wizards are inclined!) is a math formula that calculate the Index value.

So far I've come up with the following by converting formula developed for use in Excel. The Robot 2 section is incomplete. The 95 to 99 values are for error checking.

```
UPDATE MovesTable SET [Index] = 
                CASE 
                WHEN Robot = 1 THEN 
                        CASE 
                        WHEN Spot%4 = 0 THEN '99'
                        WHEN Spot = 1 or Spot = 2 or Spot = 3  THEN '02'
                        WHEN Spot = 5 or Spot = 6 or Spot = 7  THEN '06'
                        WHEN Spot = 9 or Spot = 10 or Spot = 11  THEN '10'
                        WHEN Spot%10 = 4 THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'4')                                                                               
                        WHEN Spot < 57 AND (((Spot/10)%2 = 1 AND (Spot%10)%2 = 1) AND (Spot%10 = 3 OR Spot%10 = 5)) THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'4')
                        WHEN Spot%10 = 8  THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'8')                                                                          
                        WHEN Spot < 57 AND (((Spot/10)%2 = 1 AND (Spot%10)%2 = 1) AND (Spot%10 = 7 OR Spot%10 = 9)) THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'8')
                        WHEN Spot%10 = 2  THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'2')                                                                      
                        WHEN Spot < 57 AND (((Spot/10)%2 = 1 AND (Spot%10)%2 = 0) AND (Spot%10 = 1 OR Spot%10 = 3)) THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'2')
                        WHEN Spot%10 = 6  THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'6')                                                                          
                        WHEN Spot < 57 AND (((Spot/10)%2 = 0 AND (Spot%10)%2 = 1) AND (Spot%10 = 5 OR Spot%10 = 7)) THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'6')    
                        WHEN Spot%10 = 0  THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'')   
                        WHEN Spot = 49  THEN '50' 
                        WHEN Spot < 57 AND (((Spot/10)%2 = 0 AND (Spot%10)%2 = 1) AND Spot%10 = 9)   THEN '30'                                  
                        WHEN Spot < 57 AND (((Spot/10)%2 = 1 AND (Spot%10)%2 = 1) AND Spot%10 = 1)   THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'0')                   
                        WHEN Spot > 56 AND (((Spot/10)%2 = 1 AND (Spot%10)%2 = 1) AND (Spot%10 = 7 OR Spot%10 = 9)) THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'8')        
                        WHEN Spot > 56 AND (((Spot/10)%2 = 0 AND (Spot%10)%2 = 1) AND (Spot%10 = 1 OR Spot%10 = 3)) THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'2')    
                        WHEN Spot > 56 AND (((Spot/10)%2 = 0 AND (Spot%10)%2 = 1) AND (Spot%10 = 5 OR Spot%10 = 7)) THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'6')     
                        ELSE '98'
                        END 
                ELSE 
                    CASE 
                    WHEN Robot = 2 THEN 
                        CASE
                        WHEN (Spot%2 = 0 AND Spot%4 <> 0) OR (Spot = 1 OR Spot = 2) THEN '97' 
                        WHEN Spot = 4 then '04'
                        WHEN Spot = 8  then '08'    
                        WHEN Spot%4 = 0 THEN Spot   
                        WHEN Spot = 2  OR Spot = 5  THEN '05'
                        WHEN Spot = 7  OR Spot = 9  THEN '08'   
                        WHEN Spot = 19  THEN '20'
                        WHEN Spot = 39  THEN '40'
                        WHEN Spot = 59  THEN '60'
                        ELSE '96'
                        END
                    ELSE '95'
                    END
                END
```

Comment: Aside: There seems to be some confusion over data types, e.g. `WHEN Spot%10 = 4 THEN CONCAT(Spot/10,'4')` and `WHEN Spot%4 = 0 THEN Spot`. Is `Index` a string or an integer? According to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) SQL Server will dutifully convert all of the strings into integers since a `case` expression can only return a single data type.

Comment: Yes good spotting! Should be: WHEN Spot%4 = 0 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Spot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve this mathematically, rather than by analyzing cases, etc. It matches all of your sample results:

```
declare @t table (Spot int, Robot int, [Index] int)
insert into @t(Spot,Robot,[Index]) values
(1     ,1    , 2 ),
(2     ,1    , 2 ),
(3     ,1    , 2 ),
(13    ,1    ,14 ),
(14    ,1    ,14 ),
(15    ,1    ,14 ),
(16    ,2    ,16 ),
(17    ,2    ,16 ),
(18    ,1    ,18 ),
(19    ,2    ,20 ),
(77    ,1    ,78 ),
(78    ,1    ,78 ),
(79    ,2    ,80 ),
(80    ,2    ,80 )

select *,
CONVERT(int,
ROUND((Spot +
  CASE WHEN Robot = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
)/4.0,0)* 4 -
  CASE WHEN Robot = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
) as Index2
from @t
```

The logic is "round to the nearest multiple of four" but we use a couple of expressions to offset `Robot` 1's results by 2.

Results:

```
Spot        Robot       Index       Index2
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           2           2
2           1           2           2
3           1           2           2
13          1           14          14
14          1           14          14
15          1           14          14
16          2           16          16
17          2           16          16
18          1           18          18
19          2           20          20
77          1           78          78
78          1           78          78
79          2           80          80
80          2           80          80
```

Comment: Yes you're solution works like a charm. I tested it for all values of "spot" 1 to 80 for both robots with no errors. Certainly a great improvement on my initial solution. Cheers.